# get all empty inputs and store each in unique variable

Tags: jquery, forms, event-handling

I have a form with multiple inputs, and before it gets sent I check whether any of the inputs are empty:

```
    <input type="text" name="number" id="number" style="float:left;clear:both;"/>
    <input type="text" name="road" id="road" style="float:left;clear:both;" />
    <input type="text" name="town" id="town" style="float:left;clear:both;" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" id="submit" />
```

jquery:

```
$('#submit').on('click', submitForm);
function submitForm(){
    if($('#number, #road, #town').val() ==''){
        $('#error-box').show();
        $('#error-box p').text('not all fields are complete - please complete to progress');
        return false;
    }
    else{
        alert('part 1 complete OK');
        $('#add-listing-part1').hide();
        $('#add-listing-part2').show();
        return false;
    }
}
```

I would like to display in the error box exactly which fields are empty (with a nice user friendly message), but am unsure how to do so most effectively without loads of if() statements?

logic along the lines of:

1. check if any fields are empty
2. if 'town' is empty, store 'town' in a variable, if 'road' is empty.. etc
3. change text in error box to something like - 'not all of the fields are complete, please fill in the $town and $road...'

Comment: I'd suggest you try the [jQuery validation](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) plugin before attempting to roll your own custom solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
function submitForm() {
    var empty = $('form input[value=""]');
    if (empty.length > 0) {
        $('#error-box').show();
        empty.each(function (index, element) {
            $('#error-box p').text($('#error-box p').text() + $(this).attr('name') + ' ');
        });
        $('#error-box p').text($('#error-box p').text() + 'fields are not filled');
    } else {
        // complete your submit
    }
}
```